# EXM Email Send Failure

Tags: exm

I have installed Sitecore 9.1 on my local machine - Windows 10 and trying to run a sample campaign using out of the box EXM using custom smtp (using my gmail server).

The EXM shows a success message but no email actually being sent or received.
The EXM.Master.Campaign table shows the "Status" as "Sent" but "FailedRecipients" count of all contacts (4 in my case):

[image]

I tried to get into the logs and but could not found any error. Any help is appreciated.

*Updated:*
Updated with another screen shot to give more clarity:
[image]

Comment: You might try following the blog posts here. https://sitecorehacker.com/email-experience-manager/

Comment: Also it would be helpful to know what your question is. As is, its too broad.

Comment: Not sure, why this question has been put on hold!. Thanks Pete and Pankaj for your comments. @Pete: I did follow the blog but no success. Also, I have tried to keep the question as crisp as possible - I have tried a sample newsletter from EXM and selected the list with all contacts with valid email id - after sending the campaign - EXM says campaign sent successfully and shows the status as Sent. However, no actual email is being received to contacts. I have tried to put a screen shot as well

Comment: The problem is probably your Gmail server. EXM sent the message to the SMTP, but thats as far as EXM can go. Deliverabilty is up to your SMTP server. I recommend using https://mailtrap.io for testing.

Answer (score 1):

As Pete mentioned, the issue is probably related to your smtp server. If you don't see errors in the logs, it normally means that the smtp server accepted the message(s).
It might not send the message though, or more likely mark the message as spam (could be because it does not recognize you Sitecore server). Some clients completely block those marked messages and you will think it has not been send (had a similar issue with an Office smtp server recently).

If you really want/need to use Gmail, read https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-gmail-smtp-settings-1170854 and also https://www.lifewire.com/unlock-gmail-for-a-new-email-program-or-service-1171974. Didn't try this myself, but it might help you.

But as this is on local - you might want to try using another one for testing. Maybe even just to make sure your setup in Sitecore is correct. [Mailtrap.io](https://mailtrap.io/) as mentioned by Pete is a good and very easy option that I've used as well. Setup is fairly easy and you should have no spam or blocking issues there.